# HttpURLConnection disconnect doesn't work in Android

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, illegalstateexception, disconnect

The method **disconnect** from `HttpURLConnection` seems not to work properly.
If I execute the following code:

```
url = new URL("http:// ...");
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection ();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.connect();
// Some code
connection.disconnect();
connection.setDoInput(false); // -> IllegalStateException
```

I get an `IllegalStateException` when I call the method `setDoInput`. The exception says:

> Already connected

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to reuse the connection?  i.e. altering the request properties after you've disconnected from the server, ready to make another connection.

If that is the case, then just create a new `HttpURLConnection` object.

Comment: The documentation for the disconnect method explicitly says that you should not try to reuse the connection afterward.

Comment: @Nate C-K Yes, I advocating creating a new connection. Maybe you meant to post this as an answer, or as a comment on the question??